# padding zero for hexadecimal number in php

Tags: php

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. When I pad zeros in front of a hexadecimal number it seems to change the number.

```
$number=1741;
strtoupper(dechex($number))
output is 6CD

sprintf('%03x', strtoupper(dechex($number))
output is 006
```

Comment: You don't have to use `dechex` ;) Just pass the number to `sprintf` and then it will print your number in hexadecimal representation

Comment: @Rizier123: Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The accepted answer says to use `sprintf` twice. I don't see the value in doing this twice, `%x` accepts the same padding parameters as `%d` does and so this can be done in one function call.

```
$number = 141;

$hex = sprintf('%03X', $number); // 08D
```

See: https://3v4l.org/LQrWK

So to answer the question, just remove the `strtoupper(dechex(...))` and the `sprintf` you have will work.

`echo sprintf('%03x', $number); // 06d`

`echo sprintf('%03X', $number); // 06D`

Answer (score 3):

For padding zero of a number just use `sprintf`, If you need a hexadecimal number then you need to use something like `sprintf` with a valid format for showing hexadecimal number.

**Example:**

Syntax: `sprintf(format,arg1,arg2,arg++)`

Format:

- %x - Hexadecimal number (lowercase letters)
- %X - Hexadecimal number (uppercase letters)

So, use a `sprintf` to get the `hexadeimal` number and then use another `sprintf` to get the zero padding number.

```
$number = 141;

$hex = sprintf("%X", $number); //8D
$s = sprintf('%03d', $hex); // 08D
```